# Can I add 'on' after 'decide' in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

Here's a sentence from [a blog](https://www.verbling.com/articles/post/how-to-use-articles-in-english-advanced-#:%7E:text=We%E2%80%99re%20going%20to%20a%20pub%20but%20we%20haven%E2%80%99t%20decided%20which%20one.).

> We’re going to a pub but we haven’t decided which one.

Can I change it to the following one? Is there any difference?

> We’re going to a pub but we haven’t decided **on** which one.

Comment: You can, but you don't have to.

Comment: Both phrases are correct in this case

Comment: "We’re going to a pub but we haven’t decided which", and several other variants, are also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "decide" can be either transitive or intransitive. When it's intransitive, if you want to indicate what the decision was about, you can use the preposition "on".

So yes, both sentences are correct and natural, and they have exactly the same meaning.